# Enthalpy in adiabatic process

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> A gas adiabatically expanded from $\pu{32atm}$ and $\pu{273K}$ to $\pu{1atm}$ and $\pu{251K}$, Calculate Joule-Thomson coefficient $\mu$ at $\pu{273K}$.

---

**Answer:**

$$\mu = {\Delta T \over \Delta p} = {-22 \over -31} = 0.7$$

---

I think the answer uses the definition of $\mu$ that is $\displaystyle\left({\partial T \over \partial p}\right)_H$, but this definition assumes the process to have constant enthalpy.

But in adiabatic process $dH = dU + Vdp + w_{ad}$, so for $dH = 0$ we need to have $dU + Vdp + w_{ad} = 0$ which is not possible since pressure is clearly changing and so $Vdp$ is not zero.

My questions are

1. Is $dH = 0$ for a adiabatic and I am missing something ?
2. If not then how did the author used $\displaystyle\left({\partial T \over \partial p}\right)_H$ to get the answer ?

Comment: Do you not understand how adiabatic flow through a porous plug or valve, from high pressure upstream to low pressure downstream, gives no change for the enthalpy change per mole?  Are you aware of the equation:  $$dH=C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$

Comment: No I only know $\displaystyle dH = -\mu C_pdp + CpdT$.

Comment: If you combine these two equations, you get a relationship for calculating $\mu$ from knowledge of the heat capacity and the equation of state.

Comment: Ok I subtract my equation from our equation,  $$0 = \left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P +\mu C_p\right]dP$$

How can I get rid of $C_p$ ?

Comment: You can't.  But, in any event, you did the algebra incorrectly.  What happened to the dT.

Comment: $$dH - dH=C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP -  ( -\mu C_pdp + C_pdT) =C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP +\mu C_pdP - C_pdT  = \left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP +\mu C_pdP = 0$$

can't I just cancel $dT$ ?

Comment: You want to be solving for dT/dP at constant H.

Comment: Since $H$ is constant I get $\displaystyle 0 = -\mu C_pdP + C_pdT$ or  $\displaystyle {dT\over dP } = {C_p\mu\over C_p  } = \mu$. But I did not use your equation ?

Comment: $$\mu=-\frac{\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]}{C_p}$$

Comment: @ChesterMiller But how is that useful ? since I don't know $V$ and $C_p$.

Comment: If you know the equation of state of the gas (P,V,T) and its heat capacity at constant pressure (which is also often known), you can predict in advance the JT coefficient.  But, that wasn't your question, and I was trying to address your question.  Regarding how he got his answer:  He just measured $\Delta T$ and $\Delta P$, and thus determined $\mu$ experimentally.

Comment: In this problem, calling $\Delta T/\Delta P$ the Joule-Thompson coefficient really isn't proper for such a large change in P .  The Joule-Thompson coefficient $\mu$ is, strictly speaking, defined only in terms of an infinitesimal difference in pressure between the upstream and downstream sides of the porous plug (and a corresponding infinitesimal change in the real gas temperature).  A change from 32 atm to 1 atm does not really qualify.  At best, the data provided would give a very crude approximation to $\mu$.  And the equations that we have given in terms of Cp and the EOS (continued)

Comment: (continued) would not give an accurate prediction of $\Delta T/\Delta P$ for a typical real gas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Joule-Thomson experiments occurs with no change in enthalpy.

Suppose that at the left of a porous plug there is a pressure $p_1$ and temperature $T_1$ and $p_2,T_2$ to the right of the plug, as $p_1>p_2$ the gas moves left to right. The experimental configuration must ensure that pressures remain constant and that the experiment is performed under adiabatic conditions when $q=0$.

If a volume $V_1$ of gas moves from the left to right the work done/mole is $W=p_1V_1-p_2V_2$. This is the difference between the work of compression on the left of the plug and work recovered on expansion on the right. If the gas were ideal then $w=0$, but real gases are not. The gas expansion is also adiabatic so that no heat leaves or enters then $q=0$ and the change in internal energy $\Delta U$  is equal to the net work $$\Delta U =U_2-U_1 = p_1V_1-p_2V_2$$ therefore $$U_2+p_2V_2=U_1 + p_1V_1$$
As $H=U+pV$, then  $$\Delta H = H_2-H_1=U_2 +p_2V_2-U_1 -p_1V_1 =0$$

The Joule-Thompson  coefficient $\mu$ is defined, as you write, $\left ( \partial T/\partial P \right)_H$ and this measures how much the intermolecular interactions make the gas differ from an perfect gas. Most gases cool when passing from high to low pressures at room temperature.

Notes:

The coefficient can be rewritten in other forms using
$$ \left ( \frac{\partial T}{\partial p} \right)_H \left ( \frac{\partial H}{\partial T} \right)_p \left ( \frac{\partial p}{\partial H} \right)_T =-1$$
then
$$ \mu C_p= -\left (\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}  \right)_T $$

as
$$ \frac{dH}{dP} = C_p\frac{dT}{dp} +V-T\left (\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}  \right)_p$$
then if $\alpha=(1/V)(\partial V/\partial T)_p$ is the coefficient of expansion then at constant *T*, $(\partial H/\partial p)_T= V(1-\alpha T)$ which means that the Joule-Thompson coefficient can be written as $\mu=(V/C_p)(\alpha T-1)$ (This last equation has been used as a way of measuring absolute temperature because $V,\mu$ and $ \alpha $ are all measurable quantities.

Comment: Most gases cool when passing from high to low pressures at room temperature?  Not according to Wikipedia:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect

Comment: perhaps 'most' was loose, 'many' would be better, or best only  those with positive coefficients at the prevailing temperature will cool, i.e. $\alpha T>1$

Comment: @porphyrin What is the $p$ in the partial derivative? $p_1$ or $p_2$? Why for ideal gas $w=0$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @adosar corrected typo in $\Delta H$  eqn. The last equations are general for any pressure.

Comment: @porphyrin So we can measure either the change of $T_1$ with respect to $p_1$ or $T_2$ with respect to $p_2$?

Comment: @ChetMiller  I believe that Poutin is correct for most real-world applications, i.e., those in which p_final ~ 1 atm, and p_initial is not more than ~ a few hundred atm.  In that regime, the only gases I know of which heat during a JT expansion at room temp. are hydrogen, helium, and neon. Do you know of any others? The interesting question would be what happens when the initital pressure is so high that it puts, say, N2 into a heating regime at room T -- then as its p decreased it would first heat and then cool; you could test or calc. how high p_initial would need to be for heating to win.

Comment: @theorist Why don’t you start a new thread so that we can analyze this in greater detail?

Comment: @ChetMiller That's a nice idea, but in posing the question I'd first have to see if I could derive an expression for the pressure-depence of the JT coefficient at v. high p for a specific gas. [Once I had that, I could integrate to get $\Delta T$.] I'd also need to account for a possible transition from gas to liquid or SC fluid at v. high p, which would in turn require a different expression be obtained. [Plus I'd need to think about the effect of a phase transition within a JT expansion upon $\Delta T$!] All of this requires time, so it will need to wait until I have a chance...

Comment: @theorist I think all this is doable, depending on the kind of data one has available, including large pressure drops (not just differential pressure drops).