# Find whether a gas cools or heats up on Joule-Thomson expansion

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

> A gas that follows $P(V - nb)= nRT$ is subjected to Joule-Thomson expansion. Tell whether it cools or heats up.

---

$$\mu = {\partial T \over \partial P} = {\partial P(V - nb)/nR \over \partial P} = \frac1{nR}\left(V - nb + {\partial V \over \partial P}\right) = \frac1{nR}\left(V - nb - {nRT\over P^2}\right)$$

Now how do I determine whether $\mu >0 $ or $\mu < 0$ without knowing anything  about temperature or anything else ?

Comment: The equation you gave for $\mu$ is incorrect.  That partial derivative is supposed to be at constant enthalpy H.  Do you know the mathematical relationship between dH, dT, and dP?

Comment: Yes if you mean $dH = -\mu C_p dP + C_p dT$.

Comment: I set $dH = 0$ then I get $\mu dP = dT$.

Comment: Not that part.  The next part.  Do you really think that that expression you wrote  is equal to the partial derivative of T with respect to P at constant H?

Comment: There are some details in this answer http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71543/enthalpy-in-adiabatic-process/71567#71567 . You should find that the coefficient for your gas is $-B/C_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for dH is:  $$dH=C_pdT+\left[V-T\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_P\right]dP$$